# For loop over pd.DataFrame continues running but stops working after 100 iterations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, point-clouds

I'm trying to apply an offset to every pointcloud in my list, but the offset stops applying after 100 iterations (I checked this manually). There's no error displayed.

Unfortunately you won't be able to run the code, because it uses a very large local database.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

# offset to calibrate pointclouds for open3d
x_offset = 409000
y_offset = 3660000

# read all paths from dataset and concatenate into east and west matching columns
east_points = pd.DataFrame(glob.glob("/Users/sunny/Desktop/downsampled_pointclouds/east_downsampled/*/*.ply"))
west_points = pd.DataFrame(glob.glob("/Users/sunny/Desktop/downsampled_pointclouds/west_downsampled/*/*.ply"))
points = pd.concat([east_points, west_points], axis = 1, join = "inner")
points.columns = ["east", "west"]

pointclouds_list = []
for index, row in points.iterrows():
    east_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(row["east"])
    np.asarray(east_cloud.points)[:,0] -= x_offset
    np.asarray(east_cloud.points)[:,1] -= y_offset
    west_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(row["west"])
    np.asarray(west_cloud.points)[:,0] -= x_offset
    np.asarray(west_cloud.points)[:,1] -= y_offset
    parallax_cloud = east_cloud + west_cloud
    pointclouds_list.append(parallax_cloud)
```

`east_points` and `points` each have length 23446, and `west_points` has length 24745; I don't think this contributes to the problem, but figured I'd mention it anyway.

I printed the indices, and the loop runs through all 23446 rows of `points`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide data to use, I constructed random `.ply` files using open3d and tried out your code on the randomly generated files. It seems like all of the offsets are applied from my data. You might need to provide more information about your problem if to figure out what's going wrong.

```
import os
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

# offset to calibrate pointclouds for open3d
x_offset = 409000
y_offset = 3660000

if not os.path.exists("east_points"):
        os.makedirs("east_points")
if not os.path.exists("west_points"):
    os.makedirs("west_points")

# Create random point clouds
for i in range(200):
    pcd_east = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd_west = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd_east.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10, 1000), 3))
    pcd_west.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10, 1000), 3))
    
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud(f"east_points/{i}_pc.ply", pcd_east)
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud(f"west_points/{i}_pc.ply", pcd_east)

# read all paths from dataset and concatenate into east and west matching columns
east_points = pd.DataFrame(glob.glob("east_points/*.ply"))
west_points = pd.DataFrame(glob.glob("west_points/*.ply"))
points = pd.concat([east_points, west_points], axis = 1, join = "inner")
points.columns = ["east", "west"]

pointclouds_list = []
for index, row in points.iterrows():
    east_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(row["east"])
    np.asarray(east_cloud.points)[:,0] -= x_offset
    np.asarray(east_cloud.points)[:,1] -= y_offset
    west_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(row["west"])
    np.asarray(west_cloud.points)[:,0] -= x_offset
    np.asarray(west_cloud.points)[:,1] -= y_offset
    parallax_cloud = east_cloud + west_cloud
    pointclouds_list.append(parallax_cloud)

    print(f"X offset worked for cloud at index {index}: {np.all(np.asarray(parallax_cloud.points)[:,0] < x_offset + 1)}")
    print(f"Y offset worked for cloud at index {index}: {np.all(np.asarray(parallax_cloud.points)[:,1] < x_offset + 1)}")
```

Result:

```
X offset worked for cloud at index 0: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 0: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 1: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 1: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 2: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 2: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 3: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 3: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 4: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 4: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 5: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 5: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 6: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 6: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 7: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 7: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 8: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 8: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 9: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 9: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 10: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 10: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 11: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 11: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 12: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 12: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 13: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 13: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 14: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 14: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 15: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 15: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 16: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 16: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 17: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 17: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 18: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 18: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 19: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 19: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 20: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 20: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 21: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 21: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 22: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 22: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 23: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 23: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 24: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 24: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 25: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 25: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 26: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 26: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 27: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 27: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 28: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 28: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 29: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 29: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 30: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 30: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 31: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 31: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 32: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 32: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 33: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 33: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 34: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 34: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 35: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 35: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 36: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 36: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 37: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 37: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 38: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 38: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 39: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 39: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 40: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 40: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 41: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 41: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 42: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 42: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 43: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 43: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 44: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 44: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 45: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 45: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 46: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 46: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 47: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 47: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 48: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 48: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 49: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 49: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 50: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 50: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 51: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 51: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 52: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 52: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 53: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 53: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 54: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 54: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 55: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 55: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 56: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 56: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 57: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 57: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 58: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 58: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 59: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 59: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 60: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 60: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 61: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 61: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 62: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 62: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 63: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 63: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 64: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 64: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 65: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 65: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 66: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 66: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 67: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 67: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 68: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 68: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 69: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 69: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 70: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 70: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 71: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 71: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 72: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 72: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 73: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 73: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 74: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 74: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 75: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 75: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 76: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 76: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 77: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 77: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 78: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 78: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 79: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 79: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 80: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 80: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 81: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 81: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 82: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 82: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 83: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 83: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 84: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 84: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 85: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 85: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 86: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 86: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 87: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 87: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 88: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 88: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 89: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 89: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 90: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 90: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 91: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 91: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 92: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 92: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 93: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 93: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 94: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 94: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 95: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 95: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 96: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 96: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 97: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 97: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 98: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 98: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 99: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 99: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 100: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 100: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 101: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 101: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 102: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 102: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 103: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 103: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 104: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 104: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 105: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 105: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 106: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 106: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 107: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 107: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 108: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 108: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 109: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 109: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 110: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 110: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 111: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 111: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 112: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 112: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 113: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 113: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 114: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 114: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 115: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 115: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 116: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 116: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 117: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 117: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 118: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 118: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 119: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 119: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 120: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 120: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 121: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 121: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 122: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 122: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 123: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 123: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 124: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 124: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 125: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 125: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 126: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 126: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 127: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 127: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 128: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 128: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 129: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 129: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 130: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 130: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 131: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 131: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 132: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 132: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 133: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 133: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 134: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 134: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 135: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 135: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 136: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 136: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 137: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 137: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 138: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 138: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 139: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 139: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 140: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 140: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 141: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 141: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 142: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 142: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 143: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 143: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 144: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 144: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 145: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 145: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 146: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 146: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 147: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 147: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 148: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 148: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 149: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 149: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 150: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 150: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 151: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 151: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 152: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 152: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 153: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 153: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 154: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 154: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 155: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 155: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 156: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 156: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 157: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 157: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 158: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 158: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 159: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 159: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 160: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 160: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 161: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 161: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 162: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 162: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 163: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 163: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 164: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 164: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 165: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 165: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 166: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 166: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 167: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 167: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 168: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 168: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 169: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 169: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 170: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 170: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 171: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 171: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 172: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 172: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 173: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 173: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 174: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 174: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 175: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 175: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 176: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 176: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 177: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 177: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 178: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 178: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 179: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 179: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 180: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 180: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 181: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 181: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 182: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 182: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 183: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 183: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 184: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 184: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 185: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 185: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 186: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 186: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 187: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 187: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 188: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 188: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 189: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 189: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 190: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 190: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 191: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 191: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 192: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 192: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 193: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 193: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 194: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 194: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 195: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 195: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 196: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 196: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 197: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 197: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 198: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 198: True
X offset worked for cloud at index 199: True
Y offset worked for cloud at index 199: True
```